# Using the same function yields different results?

Tags: c#, function, .net-core, .net-6.0

Going from Framework 4.5 to Net 6.0 for an old project, there is an function that has broken immensely. When using the function for the 1st time, it returns the value 1651. Running the same function for a 2nd time, it returns a 0 value. This has caused an issue where our program cannot open the PKG file properly (it fails reading the 2nd value count.). I am wondering if there's a quick fix to be done?

The File Check (The code using the broken function): [Github ArkPackage.cs](https://github.com/Mou-Ikkai/AmpForge/blob/master/Dependencies/GameArchives/Library/Ark/ArkPackage.cs#L366-L397)

```
private void readNewFileTable(Stream header, bool readHash = false)
{
  uint numFiles = header.ReadUInt32LE();
  var files = new OffsetFile[numFiles];

  for (var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
  {
    // Version 3 uses 32-bit file offsets
    long arkFileOffset = header.ReadInt64LE();
    string path = header.ReadLengthPrefixedString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    var flags = header.ReadInt32LE();
    uint size = header.ReadUInt32LE();
    if (readHash) header.Seek(4, SeekOrigin.Current); // Skips checksum

    var finalSlash = path.LastIndexOf('/');
    var fileDir = path.Substring(0, finalSlash < 0 ? 0 : finalSlash);
    var fileName = path.Substring(finalSlash < 0 ? 0 : (finalSlash + 1));
    var parent = makeOrGetDir(fileDir);
    var file = new OffsetFile(fileName, parent, contentFileMeta, arkFileOffset, size);
    file.ExtendedInfo["id"] = i;
    file.ExtendedInfo["flags"] = flags;
    files[i] = file;
    parent.AddFile(file);
  }

  var numFiles2 = header.ReadUInt32LE();
  if(numFiles != numFiles2)
    throw new Exception("Ark header appears invalid (file count mismatch)");
  for(var i = 0; i < numFiles2; i++)
  {
    files[i].ExtendedInfo["flags2"] = header.ReadInt32LE();
  }
```

The Broken Function (L154 is a variation that uses 161-171): [Github StreamExtensions.cs](https://github.com/Mou-Ikkai/AmpForge/blob/master/Dependencies/GameArchives/Library/StreamExtensions.cs#L154-L171)

```
public static uint ReadUInt32LE(this Stream s) => unchecked((uint)s.ReadInt32LE());

/// <summary>
/// Read a signed 32-bit little-endian integer from the stream.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int ReadInt32LE(this Stream s)
{
  int ret;
  byte[] tmp = new byte[4];
  s.Read(tmp, 0, 4);
  ret = tmp[0] & 0x000000FF;
  ret |= (tmp[1] << 8) & 0x0000FF00;
  ret |= (tmp[2] << 16) & 0x00FF0000;
  ret |= (tmp[3] << 24);
  return ret;
}
```

Before (Framework 4.5):[image: Before]

After (Net 6.0):[image: After]

Comment: Pay utmost attention to the documentation for the Stream.Read method. (In general it's a good idea topay utmost attention to the documentation ;-) ) It does NOT guarantee (and it never did), that it reads the requested amount of bytes even when the end of the stream is not yet reached. It's return value will tell you how many bytes it did actually read. Different implementations of the same stream type might behave differently in different .NET versions. The very same stream type might behave differently based on some incidental factors relating to the inner workings of the stream, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Starting in .Net 5, I believe it was, `FileStream.Read` doesn't block until the entire amount of data requested is available, it instead reads *at most* as many characters as instructed. Check the return value to see how much it read

If you want to read exactly as many characters as you want, either use a loop or use `BinaryReader.ReadBytes` which implements the loop for you.

Also that bit of code speaks volumes about the general quality of whatever library that is. You shouldn't be allocating arrays like that anymore, this isn't the 90's.

Comment: I'm not struggling at all, the code is objectively bad. In fact, those functions are already built into the framework now, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives.readint32littleendian?view=net-6.0

Comment: What do you mean, reverse engineering? You literally linked the source code in your question, there's no reverse engineering involved.

Comment: So, this doesn't work. But I've realized that the 1st call is still giving the proper value (It's what both runs get in Framework), but after that 1st call, using steps, all the values afterwards are null, when it's fine in framework.